# Load external template with Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

```
//path = the location of the external file
//scriptBlockId = the id of the external script block (<script id="add-form-tempate" type="text/html-template">)
//fillId = where you want to place the template when rendered
var App = Backbone.View.extend({
render: function (path, scriptBlockId, fillId) {

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        method: 'GET',
        url: path,
        success: function (response) {
            //Not sure why we have to do this first, before we can select the script block?
            var section = $('#main').append(response);

            var templateString = $(section).find('#' + scriptBlockId).html();
            var compiledTemplate = _.template(templateString);
            var temp = compiledTemplate();

            $(fillId).html(temp);
        }
    });

}
});

var app = new App();
app.render(window.siteRoot + 'Scripts/_test1.tmpl.html', 'add-form-template', '#main');
```

This code works! Why we have to append first I do not know...

Answer (score 0):

You may have had an issue w/ the aysnc `$.ajax`.

```
var App = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function(path, scriptBlockId, fillId) {
        var self = this;

        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            method: 'GET',
            url: path,
            success: function(response) {
                var templateString = $(response).find(scriptBlockId)[0].innerHTML,
                    compildeTemplate = _.template(templateString),
                    temp = compildeTemplate();

                $(fillId).html(temp);
            }
        });

        return this;
    }
});

var app = new App();
app.render(window.siteRoot + 'Scripts/_test1.tmpl.html', 'add-form-tempate', '#main');
```

I also tried to do what I think you're trying to accomplish by searching your HTML result for an id and pulling the content out of that script block.

Comment: this looks close but throws the error: TypeError: $(...).find(...)[0] is undefined

Comment: For the life of me I can't figure out why this does not work? It can bring back the external file just fine, but I cant get the code block!

Comment: @Mark Append it to `body` first maybe?

Comment: @asawyer that works, I edited the above code so it works now. I don't really understand why we append first...

Comment: @Mark try a parseHtml call over the string fragment  instead of appending to the body. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Comment: Is there any reason you have to return an html file with a script block in it? It would be a lot easier if _test1.tmpl.html was just the actual html itself...